# Tracking label's id in datalist in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am loading data from database. I want to display the content when the title is clicked by using jquery's slideToggle.

My datalist is as

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dl_news" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="ntitle" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text='<%#Eval("title")%>'> </asp:Label> </br>
     <asp:Label  ID="ncontent" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"   style=" display:none; " Text ='<%#Eval("ncontent")%>'> </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:DataList>
```

And my js is as

```
 $("#ntitle").click(function () {
        $("#ncontent").slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

The problem is that the id of lable for title and content is same for each item in datalist. Because of this only the first item on clicking shows the content, while the rest shows no reaction at all on clicking.

How do I make each item clickable and display the relative content on clicking.Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for this like,

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="ntitle" class="ntitle" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text='<%#Eval("title")%>'> </asp:Label> </br>
     <asp:Label  ID="ncontent" class="ncontent" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style=" display:none; " Text ='<%#Eval("ncontent")%>'> </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And in Jquery try,

```
$(".ntitle").click(function () {
    $(".ncontent").hide(); // first hide all
    $(this).next(".ncontent").slideDown("fast"); // slide its content, only
});
```

```js
$(".ntitle").click(function() {
  $(".ncontent").hide(); // first hide all
  $(this).next(".ncontent").slideDown("fast"); // slide its content, only
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="ntitle">First title</label>
  <label class="ncontent" style="display:none">First ncontent</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="ntitle">Second title</label>
  <label class="ncontent" style="display:none">Second ncontent</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="ntitle">Third title</label>
  <label class="ncontent" style="display:none">Third ncontent</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If i use class then on clicking one item content of all will be displayed because each have same class.

Comment: No @Chelsea it works as well. See the code snippet in my updated answer. Also, if the issue happens with you then you need to add unique id to your labels.

Comment: Ok it works good here.But It's still not working for me. I wonder why.

Comment: Remove the id attribute from your labels. then check

Answer (score 0):

Your items don't have the same Id on the client side. You can call them with this jquery line:

```
$('#<%= dl_news.FindControl("ntitle").ClientID %>').click(function () { 
    ...
});
```

/edit: But you should not use the ClientIDMode static, because this will generate invalid Html. All child controls will have the same ID.
You should use `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` on your child controls.

Comment: When I run it it says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line `('#<%= dl_news.FindControl("ntitle").ClientID %>')`